# Which classifier should I use for sparse boolean features?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data, supervised-learning, data-preprocessing

I have training data that is classified into 2 categories: **X** and **Not X**

Each piece of training or experimental data has a variable number of boolean features. Each piece of data may have ~100 features, but the total number of possible boolean features may be in the tens or hundreds of thousands.

I want to train a classifier so that given an observation (which has a set of boolean features), it will output the probability that it is **X**.

Could you recommend which ML algorithms could be used for a large number of sparse boolean features?

*Follow-up question:*

I also have a large amount of training data that would be best described as **Maybe X** (I haven't verified is **X**, but there's a good chance it is **X**). I could further segment those **Maybe X**'s into *Likely X*, *Maybe X*, *Probably Not X*. Is there a way I can train with **Maybe X** or it's subclassifications? In the end, what I still only care for is the probability that an observation is **X**.

Comment: I'm confused about your explanatory variables. Do you have very many missing observations of those variables?  Also, can you assign probabilities to your maybe X's?

Comment: Also, it is convention to call your outcome y and your explanatory variables x.

Comment: Not exactly - I'm trying to predict my outcome based on a large number of sparse features, only some of which exist in any given observation.

Comment: When you say that they do t exist, does that mean that they are unobserved or undefined?

Comment: Oh good question - it means it's unobserved. Are you saying it means that by default the rest of the variables are set to false?